# Same categories in post and easy digital download

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site with easy digital download plugin on it. I want to have same categories in posts and easy digital download. How can do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code its working and tested.

```
        add_action( 'init', 'wpshout_add_category_to_easydigital' ); 
        function wpshout_add_category_to_easydigital() 
        {
                register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'easydigital' ); // register category to custom post type "easydigital"

        }
```

Comment: I want to ```easydigital``` post type has exactly default ```category``` taxonomy.

Comment: @mshomali check the updated answer this code is tested and its working